# Send body JSON with Postman in a POST method to execute procedure in ms sql server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postman

I want to send a JSON (body) on Postman with POST method and receive a result.

Im a trainee and my boss asked me this. I've been looking in web for a week and didn't find. I said to him that method to receive a data is GET, but he said that GET has a limit on URL. If the stored procedure have a lot of parameters we will not receive the expected result, so a I have to use Post method.

This is my code to connect to ms sql server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql');


var config = {
    user: 'MY_USER',
    password: 'MY_PASS',
    server: 'MY_SERVER',
    database: 'MY_DB'
};
```

Searching in google I found a way to execute a procedure with GET method. In the browser I put the value I want and I receive the result, but is not still what he wants. The code is:

```
app.get('/get/:pNU_EST001', function (req, res) {
    //conexão com o DB
    sql.connect(config, function(){

        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.input('pNU_EST001', req.params.pNU_EST001); 
        request.execute('dbo.ESTSP004_ConsultaLivrosEmprestadosAluno_XX', function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.send(recordsets);
            //res.end(JSON.stringify(recordsets)); /*--- result in JSON format ---*/
        });        
    });
});
```

On Postman he showed me a example with DB2, but I couldn't see the code. On Post Method, on HEADERS it has two key:

KEY => Content-Type (value: application/json) // KEY => Accept (value: application/json)

And in his example, on BODY, he wrote a JSON like: { "pNU_EST001" : "3"} and received the related result below. That's what I need.

Comment: Your question sounds ok. Sorry if we were too picky here on SO. But this is necessary for the site to keep its top quality.

Comment: This is so much better than hundreds of questions I’ve seen on here. Thank you for reposting.

Comment: Just a remark on GET vs POST. You say get is for sending data. That's not quite correct. Use GET only  if the request induces no changes. Use always POST, if you send a request that modifies or adds data. Never ever use GET for this!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is it with reading in the database or with sending the request?

Comment: You say you get the results, but it is not quite what you want. So what do you get, and what do you want to get?

Comment: Lorenz, i change the app.get to app.post. I can't access the data result in the browser. Im able to access it in Postman, but I put the value 3 in the url place of Postman. I wanna write it in the Body using raw. Wanna write in raw something like: "{ "pNU_EST001" : "3"}" to receive the result

Comment: Lorenz and Danny. Im so happy. Power said what I needed. Thanks for your help and your concern.

Comment: This is not a sql-server question. please use tags properly.

Comment: Im sorry, FLYCKER. As I was using sql server too, I thought I could use this tags. What would be the correct tags?

Answer (score 0):

Express has a few other verbs to use you are using
`app.get` but there is also `app.post` if you change your code to use the latter instead it will handle a post request

```
app.post('/path', function (req, res) {
```

Then in express to get values from the `POST` body you get that from

`req.body` property

So in your case you would want to use `req.body.pNU_EST001` instead of `req.params.pNU_EST001`

Comment: Would he also need https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser or would express pick those up from the `req.body` value?

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much. I need to change the verb and change params to body. I will search now to execute a procedure from mssql to create a student. The code is pretty much the same or it is too  different?